# Unexpected useInterval and useEffect behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, counter

`counter` from the code below is needed for configuring a framer-motion animation. I need `counter` to increase by 1 with each passing second for 10 seconds but the code does not seem to be working as expected.

The problem: `counter` is increasing multiple times over (at times, counterInterval is running multiple times in a second) with each passing second and the interval isn't being cleared out when the counter hits a value over 10.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
    setCounter((prevCounter) => prevCounter + 1);
    // console.log(counter);
  }, 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log("useEffect code")
    counter >= 10 && clearInterval(counterInterval);
    // console.log("Interval Cleared!");
  }, [counter, counterInterval]);
```

Comment: Hey, as you are creating setInterval outside of useEffect, this is going to create multiple issues, including the one you have pointed here.
And, setInterval creates the same thing after each second. Seeing the example, I think setTimeout would be a better choice. 
Can you explain your code a bit? I will create a codesandbox sample to help you out here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, I may need some clarification here.
Anyway, based on what I understood, I think this code will do what you are trying to achieve here.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const counterTimeout= setTimeout(() => {
      setCounter((prevCounter) => prevCounter + 1);
    }, 1000);
    counter >= 10 && clearTimeout(counterTimeout);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(counterTimeout);
    };
  }, [counter]);

  return <div className="App">{counter}</div>;
}
```

See the [codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-forest-cchxgw?file=/src/App.js) for better understanding.